# Hardcode dates in tableau

Tags: database, tableau-api

How can I hardcode months of the year as calculated field in tableau? I need a month field in tableau that is not present in original dataset

Comment: Do you have a date to take from?

Answer (score 3):

Create a calculated field like so:

```
#1/1/2016#
```

With what ever date you need.

Comment: Can you suggest what formula I can use in tableau to create like above? I need to organize my dataset in 12 months and use the date fields in my data set to compare with those new month values? Something like if created date is less than end of month, do this or if closed date is less than the beginning of the month.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you need but there is no formula. You simply create a calculated field. If you don't know how to do that see this link. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_create.html Then inside the calculated field just write #yourdate#.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset has gaps in the values in the ***middle*** of the range for a date field, you can tell Tableau to display the missing values by selecting the "**Show Missing Values**" option for that field. This applies to discrete fields, not needed for continuous fields.

If the missing values are past the ***end*** of the range in your dataset, but you still want to leave room for the missing months or whatever, then you might need to do a little trickery. If you are treating the date as continuous, simply edit the axis and set the axis range as desired.

If the date is discrete, you have to find a way to tell Tableau that there are additional months beyond the range found in the dataset. One common way to do that in many BI environments is to create a calendar table that simply lists dates for the reporting levels you care about, and treat that as a scaffolding data source. In other words, use data blending and treat the list of months as the primary data source and the incomplete data source as a secondary source. Then you can force Tableau to have a row or column for each value in your calendar table, and display data from the other source when it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the field is just to show your data in Month increments in your worksheet, then you don't need to create a new 'Month' field. You can simply:

1. Make sure you have a field that is of type 'Date'. If the field has date information but is in text format you may need to convert it to Date (right click in the Dimensions tab)
2. Drag the field onto Rows or Columns as required
3. Right click and select 'Month' or 'Month/Year' etc as appropriate

Example:

[image: loaded from vizpainter.com/wp-content/uploads/November.png]